# Информация недоступна, символы для sfml-audio-2.dll не загружены

Tags: c++, sfml

Решил создать игру на SFML 2.6.0 . При попытке добавить в игру музыку или текстуру получаю ошибку "Информация недоступна, символы для sfml-audio-2.dll не загружены"  или "Информация недоступна, символы для sfml-graphics-2.dll не загружены" при том, что textures.png и music.ogg находятся в папке с проектом.

```cpp
    sf::Music music;
    music.openFromFile("music.ogg");
    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile("textures.png");
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(10, 10, 50, 30));
    sprite.setColor(sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 200));
    sprite.setPosition(100, 25);
    window.draw(sprite);
     
    music.play();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых картинки вместо текста - это крайне плохо. А во-вторых они не соответствуют тому, что написано в вопросе.

Answer (score -1):

Эта ошибка говорит о том, что ваш проект не знает, что такое `sfml-graphics` и `sfml-audio`, значит у вашего проекта проблемы с линковкой библиотек и бинарников, скорее всего, вы не указали в проекте папку импорта библиотек и заголовочных файлов, поищите информацию, как это правильно сделать в вашем `IDE` (и необязательно с этой библиотекой)